# Using `With` then `Delete` in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, sql-delete, with-statement

Using BigQuery I want to delete rows that has id in `Common Table Expression` or `with`

so this is my query :

```
WITH
  redundant AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at,
    COUNT(*) AS counter
  FROM
    t1
  GROUP BY
    id
  HAVING
    counter >= 2)
DELETE
FROM
  t1
WHERE
  id IN (redundant.id)
  AND updated_at NOT IN (redundant.updated_at )
```

I expected the rows will be deleted but I got this error message :
`Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT but got keyword DELETE at [13:1]`

Comment: Please review [BigQuery's DML syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
DELETE FROM `project.dataset.table` d
WHERE EXISTS (
  WITH redundant AS (
    SELECT id,
      MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at,
      COUNT(*) AS counter
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING counter > 2
  )
  SELECT 1 FROM redundant 
  WHERE d.id = id AND d.updated_at != updated_at
)
```